# Active Directory time zone

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, timezone

How can I get the Active Directory server time zone using LDAP in Java?

Comment: please,can anyone answer me?

Comment: Your question is too broad. The timezone the Microsoft Active Directory LDAP server is located within or the timezone of some value for some attribute? Generally, the timezone values for attributes are expressed either by the in the value or it is expected to be UTC.